# Connection between a Android application with admin panel

Tags: android, android-studio, database-connection

as I mention I was working on the connection between my local admin panel with the Android app the following picture is the admin panel [image] for the Android studio code

```
public interface Consts {
public static String JOB_PORTAL = "JobPortal";
public static String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.0:8080/jobportal/api";
...
```

*the IP address is my computer IP but I still can't connect to the admin panel.